# How to check connection build by datasource?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, database-connection, datasource

I have an application that connects to MYSQL database using Hibernate. We use C3P0 as connection pool.

How can I check that `dataSource` is properly configured? Or alternatively, how can I check if the database connection is build by `dataSource` or by default?

This is our configuration code:

```
  <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass">
      <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl">
      <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/springproject</value>
    </property>
    <property name="user">
      <value>root</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
      <value>tiger1</value>
    </property>
       <!-- Connection pool code start -->
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true" />
    <property name="checkoutTimeout">
      <value>600000</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxIdleTime">
      <value>30</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize">
      <value>50</value>
    </property>
    <property name="minPoolSize">
      <value>5</value>
    </property>
    <property name="initialPoolSize">
      <value>5</value>
    </property>
    <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout">
      <value>50</value>
    </property>
    <property name="maxStatements" value="2000" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="30" />
    <property name="automaticTestTable" value="c3p0_con_test" />
    <!-- Connection pool code end -->
  </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate will through an exception if the Datasource does not establish the connection with MySQL database. In order to check whether the connection established with right database you can debug and check **SessionFactory** instance which will give all the information. If the **SessionFactory** instance is null then there might some issue with the configuration.